# DataInputStream.available returns 0 when there should be data available

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am busy making an inhouse navigation application with google glass.
I am using a DataInputStream / DataOutputstream for sending orientation data from glass to android phone.

CLIENT/

```
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Socket mClientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, PORT);
        Log.d("ODSA","Client is connected");
        InputStream inputStream = mClientSocket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        isServiceRunning = true;
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (isServiceRunning) {
                int bytesAvailabe = dataInputStream.available();
                Log.d("ODSA","Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: " + bytesAvailabe);
                if(bytesAvailabe > 4) {
                    if (bytesAvailabe > 8)
                    {
                        long bytesToSkip = bytesAvailabe - 8;
                        Log.d("ODSA","BytesSkipped: " + bytesToSkip);
                        inputStream.skip(bytesToSkip);
                    }
                    Log.d("ODSA","Trying to read Azimuth");
                    float azimuth = dataInputStream.readFloat();
                    Log.d("ODSA","Trying to read Pitch");
                    float pitch = dataInputStream.readFloat();
                    String resultTxt = "Received from server - Azimuth: " + azimuth + " | Pitch: " + pitch;
                    Log.d("ODSA", resultTxt);
                    Log.d("ODSA","Sende broadcast intent");
                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    //deze wil ik eigenlijk niet hier maar krijg de reference niet te pakken in orientation service doe ik iets fout ?
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("com.odca.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED");
                    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, resultTxt);
                    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                    Log.d("ODSA","Done sending broadcast intent");
                }
                else{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO SEND ERROR MESSAGE TO ACTIVITY
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO SEND ERROR MESSAGE TO ACTIVITY
    }

}
```

SERVER/

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        //Create connection to orientation sensor
        Context startActivityContext = getBaseContext();
        this.orientationSensorManager = new OrientationSensorManager(startActivityContext);

        //Start orientation server
        ServerSocket mServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
        mServerSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mServerSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
        Log.d("ODSA","Waiting for connection on server");
        Socket mClientSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
        //TODO SEND MESSAGE TO ACTIVITY (GLASS IS CONNECTED)
        Log.d("ODSA","Server is connected");
        OutputStream oStream = mClientSocket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(oStream);
        isServiceRunning = true;
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (isServiceRunning) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long difference = endTime - lastTime;
            if(difference > 100) {
                float[] results = orientationSensorManager.getOrientationData();
                dataOutputStream.writeFloat(results[0]);
                dataOutputStream.writeFloat(results[1]);
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //TODO Send orientation data to activity
                Log.d("ODSA","Data Send to client - Azimuth: " + String.valueOf(results[0] + " | Pitch: " + results[1]));
            }
        }
        if (mClientSocket != null) mClientSocket.close();
        if (mServerSocket != null) mServerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The server is sending data just fine. and runs perfectly when testing (posting data at 100 milliseconds).

The problem is with the client code. for some reason datainputstream.available returns 0 when there should obviously be data available on the stream. Why is this happening?

I will include some logcat output for better understanding of my problem. problem is very easy to see in logcat (this was running at 1000 miliseconds interval). Any advice is welcome.

```
10-23 13:48:48.452    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 8
10-23 13:48:48.452    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:48:48.452    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:48:48.452    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 33.915466 | Pitch: 82.41343
10-23 13:48:48.452    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:48.462    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:48.462    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:49.472    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 24
10-23 13:48:49.472    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ BytesSkipped: 16
10-23 13:48:49.472    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:48:49.472    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:48:49.482    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 34.72676 | Pitch: 82.230484
10-23 13:48:49.482    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:49.502    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:49.502    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:50.502    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:51.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:52.502    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:53.502    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:54.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:55.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:56.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:57.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:58.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 776
10-23 13:48:58.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ BytesSkipped: 768
10-23 13:48:58.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:48:58.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:48:58.512    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 33.074875 | Pitch: 82.22403
10-23 13:48:58.522    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:58.532    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:58.532    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:48:59.542    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 64
10-23 13:48:59.542    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ BytesSkipped: 56
10-23 13:48:59.542    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:48:59.542    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:48:59.542    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 32.31331 | Pitch: 81.64859
10-23 13:48:59.552    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 16
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ BytesSkipped: 8
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 32.404648 | Pitch: 82.11532
10-23 13:48:59.572    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:59.582    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:48:59.582    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 0
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 72
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ BytesSkipped: 64
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Azimuth
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Trying to read Pitch
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Received from server - Azimuth: 32.3553 | Pitch: 82.41276
10-23 13:49:00.592    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Sende broadcast intent
10-23 13:49:00.612    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Done sending broadcast intent
10-23 13:49:00.612    2897-3214/com.odca D/ODSA﹕ Waiting for bytesAvailable: Real bytes available: 16
```

Comment: why not using while(dis.read() > -1)   avaiilable's javadoc says "Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over)..."

Comment: I already tried this it doesn't make a difference. The problem is that it returns 0 when there should be data. you can see in the logcat. there is no data available for 9 seconds, and then suddenly 776 bytes are available. very strange.

Comment: underlying (or wrapped inputstream by datainputstream) may cause this. but dis.read() never returns -1 if the end of stream is reached.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, same problem still occurs. It reads perfectly for about 20 - 25 seconds. then suddenly for 8 seconds there is no data available :(

Answer (score 0):

It isn't actually obliged to return a non-zero ever, and many implementations don't. For example, an SSLSocket that has only received part of an SSL record may have no idea how long the data is going to be, and for years it always returned zero.

Just get rid of the `available()` call and the skips, read everything, and block in the `read()` method, or in this case the `readFloat()` method when there isn't any input.